# Jenkins cobertura plugin - comparison of code coverage reports

Tags: jenkins, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

does anybody know if Cobertura provides possibility to automatically compare code coverage reports of two builds? If needed, I am always doing it manually in separate tabs in browser, which takes some time for larger modules